# Skip card - Phase 10

Tags: phase-10

When playing phase 10, If I have a skip card in my hand and it’s my turn to play, do I have to pull a card before I play my skip card?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

The skip card does not have any special rules about when it can be played; you discard it the same way you play any other card; and it does something special when you do.

> On your turn, draw one card, either the top card from the draw pile or the top card from the discard pile, and add it to your hand. End your turn by discarding any one of your cards onto the top of the discard pile.
>
> SKIP CARDS: Skip cards have only one purpose: to cause
> another player to lose a turn. To use, simply discard the “Skip” card on your turn, then choose the player who will lose a turn.

Comment: And note that if you did not draw before playing skip cards, your hand would become permanently smaller which could cause some phases to become impossible to complete (e.g. if you played two skips in phase 6, reducing your hand size to 8 so you could never get a run of 9).